# language change not working after publishing in google play

Tags: java, android, localization

I'm changing apps language manually by java code! but when I published the app in Play Store change language doesn't work anymore!

Answer (score 1):

Add build.gradle file (if you are uploaded app bundle).

```
bundle {
            language {
    
                enableSplit = false
            }
            density {
                // This property is set to true by default.
                enableSplit = true
            }
            abi {
                // This property is set to true by default.
                enableSplit = true
            }
        }
```